# Convert to dataframe error

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to make a dataframe with 110 columns, so i create a class with 110 attributes when i try to convert the rdd to dataframe.

```
case class Myclass(var cin_nb:String,...........,var last:String)
import sqlContext.implicts._
file2.map(_.split("\t")).map(a=>Myclass(a(0),a(1),a(2),a(3),.....a(110)).ToDf()
```

I got this error:

```
not enough arguments for method apply: (cin_nb: String,...........,last:String)
```

i'm using scala and spark 1.6.  Thank you

Comment: missing a word . should be `case class Myclass(var cin_nb:String,...........,var last:String)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because there is a hard limit of 22 columns with case classes / StructType schemas. This is due to the Tuple in scala only supporting 22 elements!! To grow a dataframe to more columns you need to expand it using the `.withColumn` function, or load from file directly into a Dataframe. For example, from parquet, or using the databricks csv parser.

Edit: An example of how to do this with `.withColumn`

```
import scala.util.Random

val numCols = 100
val numRows = 5
val delimiter = "\t"

def generateRowData = (0 until numCols).map(i => Random.alphanumeric.take(5).mkString).mkString(delimiter)

val df = sc.parallelize((0 until numRows).map(i => generateRowData).toList).toDF("data")

def extractCol(i: Int, sep: String) = udf[String, String](_.split(sep)(i))

val result = (0 until numCols).foldLeft(df){case (acc,i) => acc.withColumn(s"c$i", extractCol(i,delimiter)($"data"))}.drop($"data")

result.printSchema
result.show
```

Comment: i can't load from the file directly into a Dataframe; i have to filter some lines (copyrights lines) from the file.

Comment: You will need to use the .withColumn option then... load everything into a Daraframe of a single column, then parse out bits from that column using udf

Comment: just added an example for you

Comment: thank you bro; i will tell you if it works with me. thank you so much

Comment: i used your example and i couldnt get a solution maybe (i didn't understand , i'm beginner)
I want to share an idea with you : if i can use an udf and parse the class to the dataframe ; is that correct?
or may you more explain you solution 
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: val df = file2.toDF ("raw")

Comment: hey ; [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imw04.png) i got this error brother

Comment: You have df defined multiple times. You cannot assign something to a val multiple times

Comment: thank you for your help and support i got a problem with the content of the columns changed may you explain me why ?

Comment: You need to update the example I gave to use your own dataframe, not the one I used in the example

Comment: Can you see this image please: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf2cV.png)