# dataframe enrich the columns error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

i tryed to create a class with more than 100 attribues and parse it to dataframe but i got an error with :

```
I got this Error: too many arguments for unapply pattern, maximum = 22
```

So i try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143521/convert-to-dataframe-error/43143620?noredirect=1#comment73463385_43143620), but it generate arbitrarily the values of every columns which it's not my case ;
this is how my rdd look like:

```
            N1           N2       N3           N4       N5               Nn
        32055680    16/09/2010 16:59:59:245 16/09/2016 17:00:00:000 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        32055680    16/09/2010 16:59:59:245 16/09/2016 17:00:00:000 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        32055680    16/09/2010 16:59:59:245 16/09/2016 17:00:00:000 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        32055680    16/09/2010 16:59:59:245 16/09/2016 17:00:00:000 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        32055680    16/09/2010 16:59:59:245 16/09/2016 17:00:00:000 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

i want to convert it to spark sql like this schema

```
    |      N1    |         N2       |     N3         |      N4      |          N5     |    Nn |
    | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    |   32055680 |   16/09/2010     |   16:59:59:245 |  16/09/2016  |   17:00:00:000  | xxxxx |
    |   32055680 |   16/09/2010     |   16:59:59:245 |  16/09/2016  |   17:00:00:000  | xxxxx |
    |   32055680 |   16/09/2010     |   16:59:59:245 |  16/09/2016  |   17:00:00:000  | xxxxx |
    |   20556800 |   16/09/2010     |   16:59:59:245 |  16/09/2016  |   17:00:00:000  | xxxxx |
    |   32055680 |   16/09/2010     |   16:59:59:245 |  16/09/2016  |   17:00:00:000  | xxxxx | 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my RDD:

```
val file = spContext.textFile("C:/***/files/ze.xl3")
val file2 = file.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 > 5).map(_._1)
```

I'm using this example :

```
    import scala.util.Random
    val numCols = 100
    val numRows = 5 
    val delimiter = "\t"
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(spContext)
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import sqlContext.implicits._
def generateRowData = (0 until numCols).map(i => Random.alphanumeric.take(5).mkString).mkString(delimiter)
val df = spContext.parallelize((0 until numRows).map(i => generateRowData).toList).toDF("data")
def extractCol(i: Int, sep: String) = udf[String, String](_.split(sep)(i))       
val result = (0 until numCols).foldLeft(df){case (acc,i) => acc.withColumn(s"c$i", extractCol(i,delimiter)($"data"))}.drop($"data")
result.printSchema
result.show
```

My question is how to enrich the columns with the data of my rdd ?
Thank you

Comment: Concerning your first error `too many arguments for unapply pattern, maximum = 22`, which version of Spark and Scala are you using ? If you use Scala 2.10, try to upgrade to Scala 2.11 and a corresponding Spark version (case classes in Scala 2.10 can only have 22 attributes max)

Comment: The solution is in the other answer. Change the df to be your df instead of the one in the example! SO isn't a consultancy service, the answer is there. People cannot write the entire program for you.

Comment: @BenHorsburgh thank you for your answer; yes i changed the df of this example to mine ; but i was asking how to extract data from the rdd (mapping them? and for how much rows ? and i some fields is empty?) i didnt ask peaple to write my programe i ask them to help me with ideas

Comment: @L.CWI i'm using cloudera with spark 1.3 and scala 2.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 val numCols = 104
val delimiter = "\t"
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(spContext)
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val file = spContext.textFile("C:/***/files/ze.xl3")
val file2 = file.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 > 5).map(_._1)
val df = file2.toDF("raw")

def extractCol(i: Int, sep: String) = udf[String, String](_.split(sep)(i))       
val result = (0 until numCols).foldLeft(df){case (acc,i) => acc.withColumn(s"c$i", extractCol(i,delimiter)($"raw"))}.drop($"raw")
result.printSchema
result.show
```

Comment: hey , i got this error :  `Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$Astelia$$extractCol$1$1: (string) => string) ` Thank you

Comment: `import scala.util.Try
def extractCol(i: Int, sep: String) = udf[Option[String], String](s => Try(Some(s.split(sep)(i)))).getOrElse(None)`

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter is tab? Are you sure you have enough columns on every line?

Comment: Hey @Ben i got this error ; may you explain me why i got it please `Multiple markers at this line:
◾type mismatch; found : scala.util.Try[String] required: Option[String]
◾type mismatch; found : scala.util.Try[String] required: Option[String]
◾Call-by-name parameter creation: () ⇒ s.split(sep)(i)`

Comment: Sorry I updated my comment, probably after you copied it... can you try again?

Comment: yes i try again and i have this error:  `Multiple markers at this line:
◾type mismatch; found : scala.util.Try[Some[String]] required: Option[String]
◾type mismatch; found : scala.util.Try[Some[String]] required: Option[String]`

Comment: `def extractCol(i: Int, sep: String) = udf[Option[String], String](s => Try(Some(s.split(sep)(i))).getOrElse(None))` - bracket in wrong place

Comment: thank you it's working you ; may you explain me the extractCol function

Comment: udf[OUTPUT, INPUT1, INPUT2, ..., INPUT22]( <function>` - so we give it a string, and it outputs an optional string. think of the <function> bit like a `map` function. It just splits the input columns by tabs, and returns the part in the column we want. Since you needed the Try to make it work (error checking), then one of your rows doesn't have enough columns. If you get stuck trying to figure out which rows, please open a new question.

Comment: thank you i undrestand now how your method work @ben

Comment: hey @ben when i try it localy it work well; but when i use it in the cluster i got an error with `.drop($"raw")` i'm using spark 1.3

Comment: If you check the docs you'll see that this isn't part of 1.3 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html). You will need to remove this, and instead select all the columns you want to keep. Please can you accept the answer to your original question if it works.

Comment: thank you ;is that working with spark 1.6? i accept your answer thank you for your help